# Console appear automatically in every web page

Tags: browser, windows-console

When I browse any page, Inspect element appear in screen. Console shows some error code like,
403, 404, 400.It happened every single minute. Even when I write my question in stack overflow, it appears four or five times. It's impact in my device too. It's really disgusting, it hampers my workflow.
I really need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic 404-error is annoying for webmasters and users. If 404-errors accumulate, this can be a sign for users and search engines that the website is badly maintained. 404 errors can be identified using a number of tools, for example the Google Search Console, or the Ryte Suite.

It is also advisable to create a special 404 error page so that usability is not affected.

Humor is often used on 404-error pages, or a search bar to animate users and encourage them to search for the desired content on the target page.

A 404 error page should contain the following elements:

Polite or humorous apology for the mistake
Alternatives to the desired page, the desired product (for example, online stores), or alternative articles (such as blogs)
Option for the user to report the error so that it can be removed
Direct reference to the main navigation
A separate search bar to search for further content
Design of the error page to conform to the corporate design so that it is not perceived as a foreign object
Contact options
If you manage to keep the visitor on your website despite a 404-error page, the purpose of a proper 404-error page would be achieved and it would decrease the bounce rate and possibly still make a conversion.

[Source](https://en.ryte.com/wiki/Status_Code_400)